# Error While Renaming An Extracted Zip File To Other Languages In PHP

Tags: php, unicode, php-ziparchive, renaming, thai

I use PHP ZipArchive class to extract a .zip file, It works fine for English, but cause problems in my local language (THAI).

I use `icov('utf-8','windows-874',$zip->getNameIndex($i))` to convert utf-8 to THAI. It works for folder's/file's name, but doesn't work for extracted .zip file and cause this error :

> iconv(): Detected an illegal character in input string

Can anyone please tell me what the problem is here?

My PHP code

```
$file = iconv('utf-8', 'windows-874', $_GET['File']);
$path = iconv('utf-8', 'windows-874', $_GET['Path']);

$zip = new ZipArchive;
if ($zip->open($file) === TRUE) {
    // convert to Thai language
    for($i = 0; $i < $zip->numFiles; $i++) {
        $name = $zip->getNameIndex($i);
        //echo iconv("charset zip file", "windows-874", $name);
        //$zip->extractTo($path,$name); -> this problem
    }
    $zip->close();
    echo json_encode('unZip!!!');
} else {
    echo json_encode('Failed');
}
```

After I extract the zipped file, The file's name is not the one I set for it.
[image: After I extract the zipped file, The file's name is not the one I set for it.]

This is name i try to set : 
[image: This is name i try to set :]

Here is my zipped file :

https://www.dropbox.com/s/9f4j04lkvsyuy63/test.zip?dl=0

UPDATE 
I tried unzipping the file in windows XP, it works fine there but not in windows 7.

Comment: Nobody can tell unless you show what the string actually contains. (ZIP files aren't actually renowned for Unicode support. Most tools just use local charsets asis.)

Comment: Where is the code you use for actually extracting the content? Could you upload a minimal example of a zip file that gives the error somewhere (after adding the code you use to extract its contents)?

Comment: but it is not better to work the "THAI" with `utf8` anyway?
What is the need to convert it to `windows-874`?

Comment: My directory is thai language and I use $zip->open($file) is Fail but I convert to windows-874 is work for me

Comment: You have not provided enough information, most likely this is not a direct problem with the language, it sounds like your file is not a valid zip, this happens all the time in php because of an extra bit in the zip binary, and things like that. Are you downloading via web from a server?  Run the following command on linux: zip -T filename.zip and tell us the output.

Comment: I stumbled onto a project that fixes just many encoding issues regarding encoded names of files. I think [this](https://github.com/julp/ImprovedZipArchive) might help.

Comment: Sorry, I'am very busy and I change file name and directory to english. Thank you very much for help

Answer (score 1):

You probably should try [mb_detect_encoding()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mb-detect-encoding.php) for help with this - see the code below.   You may need to expand on this code if you also have a problem with its path.  Just use a loop if you need to do that.

```
$file = iconv('utf-8', 'windows-874', $_GET['File']);
$path = iconv('utf-8', 'windows-874', $_GET['Path']);

$zip = new ZipArchive;
if ($zip->open($file) === TRUE) {
    // convert to Thai language
    for($i = 0; $i < $zip->numFiles; $i++) {
        $name = $zip->getNameIndex($i);
        $order = mb_detect_order();
        $encoding = mb_detect_encoding($name, $order, true);
        if (FALSE === $encoding) {
             throw new UnexpectedValueException(
                sprintf(
                    'Unable to detect input encoding with mb_detect_encoding, order was: %s'
                , print_r($order, true)
                )
             );
        } else {
            $encoding = mb_detect_encoding($name);
            $stringUtf8 = iconv($encoding, 'UTF-8//IGNORE', $name);
            $zip->extractTo($path,$stringUtf8);
        }  
    }
    $zip->close();
    echo json_encode('unZip!!!');
} else {
    echo json_encode('Failed');
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your code, but doesn't work and I change to english. It's easier than Thai file name. Thank you very much